# Tweepy seems to be closing randomly

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm currently trying to collect tweets using tweepy. I am using the basic example program that comes with tweepy, however I modified it to write to a file. Sometimes my program runs for 12 hours and sometimes for one, but it seems to randomly close with no error message. Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream


# Go to http://apps.twitter.com and create an app.
# The consumer key and secret will be generated for you after
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""

# After the step above, you will be redirected to your app's page.
# Create an access token under the the "Your access token" section
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""
f = open('filename.txt', 'w')
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    """ A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.

    """
    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        f.write(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['keyword'])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible there is a :timeout" of sorts? Where if no tweets containing your `keyword` are received in X time the program terminates?

Comment: Could be, however I am usually running two of these at the same time, with very similar keywords. The one usually closes and the other usually carries on.

Comment: And there is no error or stack trace?

Comment: Nothing pops up, it just closes :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a try, except block and your Stream error will print to STDOUT.  You can catch the error in the except block and restart your script, or log the error.

```
try: 
    stream.filter(track=['keyword'])
except Exception, e:
    print "error: %s" % str(e)
    # log error or restart script
```

My guess as to why it's crashing is due to a similar, common error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```